# Detect when a profile is closed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm new to chrome extension my question is "we'll it's in the title"

basically I am trying to create an extension that works for users both with multiple profiles on chrome and just single. its going to be like "Master password+" I know that chrome have an extension called secure profile which works great for users with just one profile on their chrome browser.

I am trying to make something similar but with the extension to have the ability to detect when the profile is closed. so if password is incorrect profile closes "and even if their are other active chrome profiles already opened" when the users tries to re-open the profile again it will still ask for a password.

so if anyone knows a way of detecting when a profile (not just the chrome window) is closed so that the extension can be reset or something. please let me know and thanks for any help provided

Answer (score 0):

Okay Figured this out.. it was as simple as using

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(window) {
    localStorage["ProfileWindow"] = "Closed";
});

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(window) {
_ProfileWindow = (localStorage["ProfileWindow"] != undefined) ? localStorage["ProfileWindow"] : "Closed";

if(_ProfileWindow == "Closed") {
   localStorage["ProfileWindow"] = "Open";
}
```

Basically using localstorage to keep a permanent record of whether or not the window is open or closed.. this works a treat although I think alteration could be used.